# Vue: Two-step element drawing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building an app in Vue, and for one part of it I need to use a complicated layout algorithm to position a large number of SVG elements where the size of each element is one of the inputs to the layout algorithm.

If I was doing this in vanilla JS, I would do something like this:

1. Render all of the elements
2. Use `HTMLElement.offsetHeight` and `HTMLElement.offsetWidth` to get the rendered size of each element.
3. Run my layout algorithm
4. Reposition all of the elements.

What would be the most canonical approach to this situation in Vue?

Below is a (non-runnable) snippet that hopefully describes my problem clearly. Please let me know if this is not clear and I will try to make a more complete example.

```
<template>
 <svg>
  <g v-for='node in nodes'>
   <rect :x='node.position.x' :y='node.position.y' :height='node.height' :width='node.width'/>
  </g>
 </svg
</template>

<script>
  export default {
      name: 'Nodes',
      props: {
        node_data: Object
      },
      computed: {
        nodes() {
           // get_rect_sizes needs to inspect the rendered svg elements (which do not exist yet)
           var rect_sizes = get_rect_sizes(node_data);
           return do_layout(node_data, rect_sizes);
        }
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Let's pretend for a minute that your SVG was not embedded into an HTML document but lives on its own. How would you run your layout algorithm ? There is such thing in the SVG world as `width: 100%` or `height: auto` - SVG elements always have explicit and fixed coordinates/dimensions. So you always know their width/height. If you are trying to implement the Flexbox algorithm for SVG - look here (https://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/02/svg-layout-flexbox.html)

Comment: In reply to the first point, if I have  `<text>` element, I can use `getBBox()` to find out it's rendered width. If I wanted to find out the width of the text box without embedding it, I would still need to render it somehow. To answer the second question, what I trying to do is set up a directed graph visualisation that uses a 3rd party layout algorithm (Dagre).

Comment: You can put another SVG behind your real one (`z-index: -1;visibility: hidden;`) which will hold duplicates of all your `<text>` elements. Then you can call `getBBox()` for each of these duplicates, produce the layout, and then position the real `<text>` elements in the first SVG.